# Cannot run production build

Tags: nestjs

I am developing API with nestjs and TypeORM connected with PostgreSQL. NestJS is using `ormconfig.json` file to provide database connection.

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "xyz",
  "password": "xyz",
  "database": "xyz",
  "entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

When in dev mode `npm run start:dev` everything works OK, API is responding, connected properly with database. But when I try run production build: `npm run prestart:prod` followed by `npm run start:prod` something breaks and program cannot connect to the database, that cause error:

```sh
[Nest] 12444   - 2019-04-09 22:19   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 12444   - 2019-04-09 22:19   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +85ms
[Nest] 12444   - 2019-04-09 22:19   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 12444   - 2019-04-09 22:19   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +111ms
C:\_code\sensorhub\packages\api-nestjs\src\installations\models\installation.entity.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[Nest] 12444   - 2019-04-09 22:19   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +3130ms
```

installation.entity.ts

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class InstallationEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500 })
  name: string;

  @Column('text')
  description: string;
}
```

I think that code itself is correct, but there is something wrong with proper configuration.

nestjs `ver.6.0.0`

Comment: try changing `"entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"]`, to `"entities": ["src/**/**.entity.ts"]`

Comment: @shusson, unfortunately still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/184
using a dynamic ormconfig.js (instead of .json)